# Is there a way to automatically share objects from one S3 bucket to another by file name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cloud

So in my company theres two S3 buckets, one stores all of the reports and another is supposed to store a particular type of report called accountingEOMReport which is ran once a month, right now we're trying to pull the EOM reports from bucket 1 but the code isn't saving it there, instead it's saving to bucket 4 (this wasn't a problem before and only started after we began using S3). What I want to do is create some sort of policy rule or Lambda function to automatically search bucket for for a particular type of file name (eg EOMReport or something like that) and move those to bucket 1, maybe once per day or a few times a week. This report is run once or a few times a month so maybe to the storage option that works best for that but that can still be retrieved within a few hours max worst case scenario.

Comment: There's no policy option here. Rather than have a Lambda function search for these objects, it would be more typical to configure S3 to trigger a Lambda function each time an object is uploaded to bucket 4 and have that function take the appropriate action (move objects matching some key pattern to bucket 2). For the one-time move of existing objects, write a script (or use S3 Batch if it's millions of objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Configure the Amazon S3 bucket to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever a new object is created
- You could then code the AWS Lambda function to check the name of the object that was created. If it is an `EOMReport`, then the Lambda function should:

  - Copy the object to the other bucket
  - Delete the original object (if desired)

This will happen immediately upon creation of the object, so there is no need to schedule it. AWS Lambda is charged per-millisecond and there is a monthly Free Tier for AWS Lambda. As a result, this solution will likely not cost you anything.